# Is my LESS getting included twice?

Tags: magento2, theme, less

As part of creating a custom theme, and partially following the guide on the [Magento site](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html), I added a LESS file at:

```
<theme-dir>/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

When I view the CSS in Firebug, it looks like all of my styles from this new file are being used twice on the same element, as if its including `_extend.less` twice.

[image: see example]

About my setup:

- Magento is in Development mode
- LESS compilation is set to client-side

  - I confirmed I am still seeing this with server-side compilation
- Cache is disabled

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think it's due to the client-side compilation, it seems to add the same code twice. I think it's related to debugging tools. You can confirm by setting it back to server side.

Comment: After switching to server-side compilation (and clearing static files, cache, indexing), I am still seeing my styles double-included

Comment: Hmm, to try and debug I can think of: 

- If you inspect the code and search for '.css' are there any duplicate CSS files? 

- Look at the css files and check if the duplicates are actually there 

- Have you extended or overwritten styles.less (or styles-l/styles-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into this a bit more I think it's down to `styles-l.less` and `styles-m.less` as they both import the same code unless specified with the @media-common variable.

You can read more on this by going to `file:///**PATH-TO-LOCAL-MAGENTO-2-INSTALL/lib/web/css/docs/responsive.html` - I need to access this on my OS and not within the virtual box. I also need to open it in Firefox as it's buggy in Chrome.

The relevant section is:

## Media query style groups separation variables

**@media-common: true|false** - sets whether to output common styles. For common styles every time you want to add some styles you should use

```
  & when (@media-common = true) {
      your styles
  }
```

**@media-target: all|desktop|mobile** - Sets target device for styles output

```
  & when (@media-target = 'mobile'),
  (@media-target = 'all') {
     @media only screen and (max-width: (@screen__xs - 1)) {
         .media-width('max', @screen__xs);
     }
 }
```

#### Gathering

Everything that you include in collector mixins above will go in place where they declarated. As example all

```
  .media-width(@extremum, @break) {
      your code
  }
```

Will go to

```
  .media-width(@extremum, @break));
```

## Example

I've taken this example from `var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/PartyShowroom/default/en_GB/Magento_Catalog/css/source/_widgets.less`

**Desktop and mobile**

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    ... LESS HERE ...
}
```

**Mobile**

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = 
    @screen__s) {
        ... LESS HERE ...
    }
```

**Desktop**

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    ... LESS HERE ...
}
```

## TL:DR

You can use the @media-target variable to set whether to output that code block to styles-l.css, styles-m.css or both.

More info can be found in:

- `var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/**STORE-NAME**/**THEME-NAME**/en_GB/css/source/lib/_responsive.less`
- `file:///**PATH-TO-LOCAL-MAGENTO-2-INSTALL/lib/web/css/docs/responsive.html`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense; Adding the common media query did the trick!

Comment: I asked a question as to why it is useful, it's been answered here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112715/media-common-why-do-we-need-to-use-this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the note from devdocs

> If working on a theme which inherits from either the Blank or Luma theme, it’s recommended to use .media-width() and style groups separation. Otherwise the style rules will be added twice, once to styles-m.css and once more to styles-l.css.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html