# @media-common - Why do we need to use this?

Tags: magento2, less-css, less, static-content

In the Magento 2 lib documentation it contains the following:

**@media-common: true|false** - sets whether to output common styles. For common styles every time you want to add some styles you should use

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    your styles
}
```

### Question

What is the difference between using this and just writing Less without it? Such as:

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    body {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

How does that compile differently to:

```
body {
    background: blue;
}
```

Won't it be outputted in styles-l.css and styles-m.css regardless?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Magento 2 follows [Mobile First approach](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html) and **@media-common = true** was designed to define styles that are base (mobile) and must be present in `styles-m.css`. If you drop this declaration styles will be outputted both to `styles-m.css` and `styles-l.css` files.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, thank you. So when media-common = true it will only output to styles-m.css,  and setting media-common = false is the same as not using it at all?

Comment: Yes. Actually **media-common: false;** is used in `styles-l.less` only. So I don't think someone will ever set it to `false` on purpose, unless for some custom stand-alone css file, maybe? By the way for Backend styles you can use both: **@media-common** or drop that declaration, as all styles are on the single css file.

Comment: On non-mobile display magento adds `styles-l.less`, so all styles from `styles-m.less` still apply, so why code outside **media-common:true** is added to both files?

Comment: @Volvox exactly. Because not using **media-common:true** will output the style to both `styles-l.less` and `styles-m.less`. While with using *media-common:true* it will output style in style-m but it will be actually applied to both mobile and desktop! I'm gonna check it now to make sure.